# How do I convert heapbytebuffer to "File"?

Tags: java

I have a heapbytebuffer in a variable "myByteBuffer" that represents an audio wav that I want to playback. I see that AudioInputStream is a way to play files using AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile). Since it accepts a "File", how can I convert the heapbytebuffer I have to a "File"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `File` overload unless you have (or want to save) a physical file. Just take your data and wrap it in an `InputStream`:

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteBuffer.array()))
```

This assumes you're using the full buffer. If not, you can slice out the part you're using as necessary. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679298/gets-byte-array-from-a-bytebuffer-in-java) for details.