# socketchannel get bytes array from ByteBuffers

Tags: android

```
ByteBuffer[] output = new ByteBuffer[256];
socketChannel.read(output);
```

android. i want to get bytes array from ByteBuffer**s**. not ByteBuffer

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do.

If what you want is to retrieve the bytes that are remaining (between position and limit), then what you have will work. You could also just do:

ByteBuffer bb =..

byte[] b = new byte[bb.remaining()]
bb.get(b);
which is equivalent as per the ByteBuffer javadocs.

Reference from Jason S ([Gets byte array from a ByteBuffer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679298/gets-byte-array-from-a-bytebuffer-in-java))

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteBuffer[] output = new ByteBuffer[256];
ByteBuffer output = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);
```

its different. output.get no works with my code