# Extra bytes being added to serialization with BooPickle and RocksDb

Tags: scala, rocksdb, upickle

So I'm using BooPickle to serialize Scala classes before writing them to RocksDB. To serialize a class,

```
case class Key(a: Long, b: Int) {

def toStringEncoding: String = s"${a}-${b}"
}
```

I have this implicit class

```
  implicit class KeySerializer(key: Key) {
    def serialize: Array[Byte] = 
      Pickle.intoBytes(key.toStringEncoding).array
  }
```

The method `toStringEncoding` is necessary because BooPickle wasn't serializing the case class in a way that worked well with RocksDb's requirements on key ordering. I then write a bunch of key, value pairs to several SST files and ingest them into RocksDb. However when I go to look up the keys from the db, they're not found.

If I iterate over all of the keys in the db, I find keys are successfully written, however extra bytes are written to the byte representation in the db. For example if `key.serialize` outputs something like this

```
Array[Byte] = Array( 25, 49, 54, 48, 53, 55, 52, 52, 48, 48, 48, 45, 48, 45, 49, 54, 48, 53, 55, 52, 52, 48, 51, 48, 45, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...)
```

What I'll find in the db is something like this

```
Array[Byte] = Array( 25, 49, 54, 48, 53, 55, 52, 52, 48, 48, 48, 45, 48, 45, 49, 54, 48, 53, 55, 52, 52, 48, 51, 48, 45, 48, 51, 101, 52, 97, 49, 100, 102, 48, 50, 53, 5, 8, ...)
```

Extra non zero bytes replace the zero bytes at the end of the byte array. In addition the size of the byte arrays are different. When I call the `serialize` method the size of the byte array is 512, but when I retrieve the key from the db the size is 4112. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: You are aware that the docs for boopickle specifically say that it's not suitable for storage use-cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with RocksDb or BooPickle but I guess that the problem is in calling `ByteBuffer.array`.
It returns the whole array backing the byte buffer rather than the relevant part.

You can look e.g. here [Gets byte array from a ByteBuffer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679298/gets-byte-array-from-a-bytebuffer-in-java/679325)
how to properly extract the data from a ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

The [BooPickle docs](https://boopickle.suzaku.io/Misc.html) suggest the following for getting BooPickled data as a byte array:

```
val data: Array[Byte] = Array.ofDim[Byte](buf.remaining)
buf.get(data)
```

So in your case it would be something like

```
def serialize: Array[Byte] = {
  val buf = Pickle.intoBytes(key.toStringEncoding)
  val arr = Array.ofDim[Byte](buf.remaining)
  buf.get(arr)
  arr
}
```