# Regular expression to clean strings of words(with accents) and numbers from spaces or other characters at the beggining or end

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I'm using **python with spark** to treat some data with accent words in portuguese.

Some examples of  data comes are like this:

```
 .. -- Água, 1234 ...

 - -- https://www.example.com/page.html *****
```

I'm trying to remove anything that is not a word or number from the left or right of the string, getting clean results like this:

```
   Água, 1234
   https://www.example.com/page.html
```

The best I could do is this:

```
 ^[^\\p{N}\\p{L}]]|[^\\p{N}\\p{L}]$
```

But this didn't work. I saw a lot solutions but non matching the beginning and end of string with accent characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `REGEXP` `[a-zA-Z]` and `[0-9]`

Comment: It takes the accent words away if they are at the beginning or end

Comment: Hey I don't know why you removed your comment but it worked, thanks man :)

Comment: ops sorry, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663644/how-to-account-for-accent-characters-for-regex-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it.

Thanks to αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη, It's not the best solution because it goes outside of regexp_replace function of pyspark but it works, just added the **re.unicode** flag, and created a udf.

```py
regexp = re.compile(r'^\W+|\W+$',flags=re.UNICODE)

def remove_non_utf8(string):
    return regexp_2.sub('',regexp_1.sub('',string))

replace_utf8 = udf(remove_non_utf8)
```

This removes all non unicode characters from the begining or end, used [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663644/how-to-account-for-accent-characters-for-regex-in-python) as reference.

--EDIT--

I tried using:

```
**(?ui)^\W+|\W+$**
```

With the function **regexp_replace** of pyspark, it didn't work so I'm still with the regexp solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it'd be OK that we'd look into the data you have, then we'd write some expression similar to:

```
(?i)\S[a-z].+[a-z0-9]
```

or,

```
(?i)\S*[a-z].+[a-z0-9]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUn4L3/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JUn4L3/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/JUn4L3/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```
import re


regex = r"(?i)\S[a-z].+[a-z0-9]"
string = """
.. -- Água, 1234 ...

 - -- https://www.example.com/page.html *****
"""

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

```
['Água, 1234', 'https://www.example.com/page.html']
```