# UTF-8 display formats in java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

My problem is with utf-8 display formats,

Using link [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl);

How to get "**One Latin-1 char per byte**" format in java?

For example:
String x="Φ";
encodedString --> Î¦

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with this.

Comment: Do you mean you get a byte array and you need to construct a java string based on specific character set ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655891/converting-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-java-how-to-keep-it-as-single-byte :)