# How do I make JSONObject toString escape unicode characters?

Tags: java, json, unicode

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565486/how-do-i-make-the-tostring-of-the-jsonobject-encode-the-utf-8-characters-to-un), I need the string equivalent of a net.sf.json.JSON object expressed entirely in ASCII characters.

```
new JSONObject().put("JSON", "帮").toString();
```

to return

```
{"JSON":"\u5E2E"}
```

*not*

```
{"JSON":"帮"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a JSONObject based solution or normal java solution?

I am not sure is JsonObject have any such functionality. But a vaniall java based approach would be

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "帮";
    String s1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        s1 = s1+"\\u" + Integer.toHexString(s.charAt(i) | 0x10000).substring(1);

    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but net.sf.json is a given of the situation.